# update column and update another col from updated col

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Is this a workable solution?

```
BEGIN

 UPDATE my_table 
 SET my_column = my_value
 WHERE my_conditions,
       my_column2 = my_column --my_updated_column_value

COMMIT;
END;
```

Or how can I update multiple columns with the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be

```
update my_table 
  set my_column  = my_value,
      my_column2 = my_value      --> this
    where my_conditions;
```

---

Because, if you set it (as one of answers suggests) to

```
my_column2 = my_column
```

you'd update `MY_COLUMN2` to *old* `MY_COLUMN`'s value. Have a look:

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (my_column number,
  3   my_column2 number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (100, 200);

1 row created.

SQL> update test set 
  2    my_column = 300,           --> "300" represents "MY_VALUE"
  3    my_column2 = my_column;    --> it won't be set to 300, but to 100

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

 MY_COLUMN MY_COLUMN2
---------- ----------
       300        100

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the updates in the "set" portion of the statement

```
begin
 update my_table 
    set my_column   = my_value
       ,my_column2 = my_column --my_updated_column_value
  where my_conditions
commit;
end;
```

Comment: Not really. Doing so, you'd set MY_COLUMN2 to **old** MY_COLUMN's value, which is not what the OP wants (at least, I believe so).

Comment: You are correct i had misread the question theel op wanted to set multiple columns in one update statement rather than two seperate update statements - one for each column

Answer (score 0):

you can directly update 2 field in one statement. Here is an example.

```
drop table TAB1\\

create table TAB1  
(Col1 CHAR(1), 
 COl2 CHAR(1)
)\\



INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES ( 'A' , 'B' ) \\
INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES ( 'C' , 'D' ) \\

select * from TAB1\\

UPDATE TAB1  
SET 
COL1 = 'E',
COL2 = 'E'
WHERE COL1 = 'A' \\

SELECT * FROM TAB1\\
```

Result

```
    COL1    COL2
1   A   B
2   C   D

    COL1    COL2
1   E   E
2   C   D
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/YOGYRT49510)